# Writing a formula for an infinite sum, why doesn't this work as written?

Tags: java, sum, infinite

I an writing an infinite sum inside Java to match -

`sqrt(t)*sech(t)^2 dt` from `t=0` to `t=infinity` (An infinite sum starting from `t = 0` and then ending at `t = infinity`. I am referencing Wolfram Alpha (Mathematica) to compare my results).

In more mathematical terms, this is (essentially) what the program is doing. I note that this is squaring (hyperbolic) secant. Although, the maximum is really infinity-

```
integrate sqrt(t)*sech(t)^2 dt from t=0 to t=1000
```

To match this infinite sum, I wrote a short program below.

```
public class TestSum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
           newForm(0.5);
   }

   public static double newForm(double s) {
    int n = 0;
    double currentSum = 0;

    while (n < 1000) {
        double sech = 1 / Math.cosh(n);
        double squared = Math.pow(sech, 2);
        currentSum = ((Math.pow(n, s))*squared) + currentSum;
        if(n == 999)
            System.out.println("The current sum is " + currentSum);
        n++;
    }
    return currentSum;
   }
}
```

When I plug this into Mathematica/Wolfram I get -

```
integrate sqrt(t)*sech(t)^2 dt from t=0 to t=1000
integral_0^1000 sqrt(t) sech^2(t) dt = 0.758128
```

The result from running the program is -

```
run:
The current sum is 0.5401365941579325
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am pretty sure Mathematica isn't wrong. What is wrong with my program?

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking a sqrt somewhere?

Comment: How is this recursive? I don't see recursion anywhere

Comment: Math.pow(n,s) references the s=0.5. I am not sure if I should technically classify this as recursion (it looks similar to me, but I am much better at mathematics than at Java).

Comment: Why don't you print the result after the loop?

Comment: Which numerical integration algorithm did you use ? Also, there is nowhere sqrt(t)

Comment: `(Math.pow(n, s)`: where in the initial formula is `n^s`?

Comment: `(Math.pow(n, s)` represents `sqrt(n)`, since the method is called with `s = 0.5`. And `Math.pow(n, 0.5) == Math.sqrt(n)` (almost...)

Comment: Yes, the sum can really be Math.pow(n, <any s>). I was testing on s = 0.5. I don't think I need to use a integration algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution simply is not accurate enough.

An integral can be approximated by a Riemann Sum

[image: Riemann Summ]

see [Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) on wikipedia.

The result gets better the smaller the delta x (or in your case delta t) becomes.

In your solution `delta t = 1`, so the approximation is not really good.

The a possible solution to approximate the result better is to use:

```
public class TestSum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          double result= integrate(0, 1000);
          System.out.print("result = " + result );
   }

   public static double integrate(double start, double end) {
    double currentIntegralValue = 0;
    double dt=0.01d;
    double t = start;

    while (Math.abs(end - t) >= dt && t-end < 0) {
        currentIntegralValue += fn(t)*dt;
        t += dt;
    }
    return currentIntegralValue;
   }

   private static double fn(double t) {
        double sech = 1 / Math.cosh(t);
        double squared = Math.pow(sech, 2);
        return  ((Math.pow(t, 0.5))*squared); 
   }
}
```

result = 0.7579201343666041

You can further improve the result by using a smaller `dt`.

```
dt=0.00001d
```

result = 0.7581278135568323

Comment: Thank You, I see my mistake. I am slightly embarrassed and will continue to work on my program.